# Mysql server remote connection - many failed attempts

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I have a mysql server installed on windows machine. 
from the production machine (UNIX ubunto) there are 20-30 concurrent connections, and recently, many of them are taking a lot of time to connect, and the Failed & aborted attempts are increasing.
I know the DB server works fine, because when connecting from other machines, less crowded, i don't get this problems at all.
I've tried restarting both the mysql server & the machine, and the WEB server & Web machine (apache).
I've tried running:

```
flush hosts;
```

right after doing those actions thing are working fine for the first few attempts and then they are getting stuck again.
when i check DB status I get line like this:

```
Kill    8217    user    xx.xxx.xxx.xx:2889  groufie_db  Sleep   11
```

other connection are failing with this error (mysqli):

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xx.xx.xx' (110)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have sleeping connections which are no longer used.

Edit your MySQL configuration file (in Linux its my.cnf, I do not know what it is in Windows) and the following:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 10
```

Every connection longer than 10 seconds will be dropped. You can adjust the value to your needs.